# how to get how many times a specific value change in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the number of time number change to specific value in array.

```
 array(358) { [0]=> string(1) "6" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "6"  [3]=> string(1) "5" [4]=> string(1) "5" [5]=> string(1) "4" [6]=> string(1) "4" [7]=> string(1) "6" [8]=> string(1) "6" [9]=> string(1) "4" }
```

I want to get how many times I get value "6". like in above array i got value "6" 2 times.

Comment: use [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Comment: what does that *he number of time status change* mean ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhtrest sorry it is array name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in an example-

```
$count = 0;
$counter = -1;
$arr = array("3", "6", "6", "3", "6", "4", "4");
foreach($arr as $val){
    if($val == 6)
        $counter = 0;

    if($counter == 0 && $val != 6){
        $count++;
        $counter = -1;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: I am not asking to get how many times a value appear in array, what i mean is to get how many time value change in array. like in my array value 6 change 2 times.

Comment: @FQ, Check and let me know.

Comment: If you need any explanation than ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) - *Counts all the values of an array*:

**Example:**

```
<?php
$array = array(1,3,2,3,5,3,8,3);
$vals = array_count_values($array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($vals);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [2] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [8] => 1
)
```

[According to PHP Manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)  `array_count_values()` returns an array using the values of array as keys and their frequency in array as values.

Comment: I am not asking to get how many times a value appear in array, what i mean is to get how many time value change in array. like in my array value 6 change 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
  if ($item == 6) {
    $i++;
  }
}
echo $i;
```

Comment: I am not asking to get how many times a value appear in array, what i mean is to get how many time value change in array. like in my array value 6 change 2 times.

Comment: Your array values does not change. They are static. Would you mind explaining what you are trying to accomplish, and it might be easier to help you.